# Android responsive Website is shown in Browser, but not in Webview

Tags: android, browser, webview, responsive-design

in my app I have a webview, which should display a responsive website. The device width for showing the mobile version is limited by 767 px, so the smartphones with a 1280x720 resolution displays the mobile website correct.

When I now open the app on my s4 (resolution: 1920 x 1080) I expect the webview, to show the normal desktop website and it does. But when I open it in normal web browser like Chrome, the responsive layout is shown.

Can anyone explain that behaviour? Is it possible to also show the responsive website in my webview on the s4?

Webpage contains the following

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Greetings,
jennymo

Answer (score 1):

first of all, the s4 has a 1920 x 1080 **resolution** but this does not mean the screen is 1920 x 1080 pixels wide and high. samsung has a 3.0 device pixel density (http://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/) and this means that 1 css px is 3px (read this for more information: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html) so you have to divide that number by 3 to get the **CSS PIXEL unit which is: 640 x 360px.**

this may be why you are not seeing what you expect to see on mobile/web browser

Comment: Okay thank you for answering, but then, why is the responsive layout shown in the native web browser, but in the web view not? Doesnt behave the native browser and the webview the same? Where is the difference?

Comment: how does the desktop site differ from what you call the "responsive site"? there should be one responsive website. do you have any code or link to show?

Comment: It differs by analyzing the device-width. and with a width till 767px the site should be displayed as responsive. Unfortunately, I dont have code to show, sry.

Comment: mmm that's not exactly how it should work, a width doesn't make a website responsive. you should use a fluid layout and use mediaqueries for breakpoints and have just one website fitting nicely on any screen. it's impossible to help with no code, sorry for that

Comment: @jennymo Did you ever solve this issue? I am actually facing the same problem right now.

Comment: Unfortunatelay not...sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try writing this line of codes i am giving the example code if you didn't import **javascript** in your app first you need to enable **javascript** and then add these lines of code in the **Android webview**

```
 WebSettings webSettings = mWebview.getSettings();
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
 webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Try adding these lines it may help i tried and it works for me