# ANDROID- WebView not displaying webpage as expected

Tags: java, android, android-activity, webview, web

I have my webpage ([CYNX.ML/U1.html](http://CYNX.ML/U1.html)) which displays perfectly in all other browsers, However I am using WebView to display it to the users which seems to shown it broken.

This is how it appears on WebView- http://prntscr.com/irhosm

Any way to fix this? It seems to be displayed perfectly on all mobile web browsers- Including Chrome, Dolphin Web browser, UC web browser

***CODE of MainActivity.java-**

```
 package com.sirseni.simpleandroidwebviewexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://cynx.ml/U1.html");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");
    }

    // Use When the user clicks a link from a web page in your WebView
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.centerend.com")) {
                return false;

            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**Had to inform that I feel WebView is having slight problems with the page's css styling, however Google seems to show it as 100% mobile compatible. Any ideas?

Comment: your website is not compatible for mobile browser

Comment: But all other mobile browsers are able to display it..

Comment: try enabling java script on webview

Comment: Enabled JS, no help.

Comment: try the answers in following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363441/android-responsive-website-is-shown-in-browser-but-not-in-webview

Comment: Not of any help :(

Comment: no errors in console? like security errors?

Comment: Nope. It gives build successful at last

Comment: Hello, you should share your webview code. I will suggest you few points which might be helpful for you. (1) Check your website that whether it is responsive in Chrome by pressing Ctrl+Shift+M. (2) check if you website is responsive to mobile devices, then your webview code must have  `webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");`  
Hope it works.

Comment: Hi added code, please do have a look, it still does not work.